# Issue compiling package specification and body using Shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, unix, sh

I am trying to compile a package specification and the body into a database (Oracle) by running a Shell Script from Putty. My final target is to also register a Concurrent Program to run this package, using a .ldt file.
I have the files (.pkb and .pks) in a specific path, and I tried using the following script:

```
...
WriteMessage "Creating package XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG.pks"
RunSQLScript $XXMOB_TOP/sql/XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG.pks

WriteMessage "Creating package XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG.pkb"
RunSQLScript $XXMOB_TOP/sql/XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG.pkb
...
```

and the **RunSQLScript** is defined as follows:

```
# RunSQLScript
#  Runs the given SQL script.  The script must accept apps and custom
#  credentials (whether or not they are used)
#  $1 = filename
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
RunSQLScript()
{
  if [ $errorFlag = N ] ; then    
    WriteMessage "Running script ${1}"      
    if sqlplus -s $appsCredentials @${1} $appsCredentials $customCredentials >> $logFile
    then
      WriteMessage "Script ${1} complete."
    else
      WriteMessage "Error running script ${1} - please check the log"
      errorFlag=Y
    fi
  fi
}
```

The issue is that I get the "Running script [filename]" on the screen, but nothing after that. Neither do I get the "Script complete" message nor the Error message.

However, in the log file, after these same above messages/log texts, there is an additional "Input terminated to 26 characters". I searched and the quick fix to this was to add a '/' to the end of the script, which I did. But there was no change in the output or the log even after this. I'm not sure if that's relevant to the original problem.

The Custom and Apps Credentials are validated at the very beginning every time the script is run.

EDIT: Adding Package Spec and WriteMessage as requested by Alex

**PKS File contents**

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG
AS
/***********************************************************************************
* Company Name          : XLRI PHD
* Script Name           : XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG.pks
* Program Type          : PL SQL Package specification BOM Criticality Report
* Program Description   : BOM Criticality Report extraction from oracle EBS 11i 
* Parameters            :
* Author                : Subhasish
* Date                  : 25-OCT-2016
* Modification Details  : Date       Modified By      Comments
*                        ---------  --------------   -------------------------
* Comments              : 
*                         
***************************************************************************************/
PROCEDURE XLRI_BOM_ANALYSIS (
      ERRBUF           OUT   VARCHAR2,
      RETCODE          OUT   NUMBER,
      p_org_id         IN NUMBER
   );

END XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG
EXIT;
```

**WriteMessage:**

```
WriteMessage()
{
  echo "$1"
  echo "\n$1" >> $logFile
}
```

Comment: Do your .pks and .pkb scripts have 'exit' at the end? I suspect not from you saying you added a slash. That would cause it to appear to hang - typing exit would then let the script complete, if so. Not sure where the 'input terminated ...' message is coming from though; is that string in your .pks file?

Comment: @AlexPoole My entire script is in a .sh file, which also contains other tasks for the script to complete. The script doesn't even execute anything further than this at the moment. And my package spec and body files are in a dedicated /bin folder. Where are you suggesting I add the EXIT?

Comment: As I said, at the end of the `.pks` and `.pkb` files. When you run a SQL script with `@` SQL\`*Plus doesn't automatically exit, you have to tell it to. Initially I'm trying to establish if you do already have an exit in your SQL scripts; if not then one needs to be added.

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried entering EXIT when the script was running and appeared to hang. But that didn't help. Should I just add "EXIT", and nothing else,  at the end of the two files?

Comment: I'm having to guess - it might help to show your `.pks` file (or a simple example that shows the same issue, if you don't want to show real code). I'm wondering if the `Input terminated...` message is coming from your `WriteMessage` function, which you also haven't shown, but I'm not sure it's relevant.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've added the EXIT as you suggested and pasted the pks file contents in the orginals post. Also, the WriteMessage function is basically a echo command. I'm more concerned about the package compilation getting stuck every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package specification is incomplete. The `END` needs to be terminated with a semicolon, and [the whole PL/SQL section needs to be terminated with a slash](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663) - otherwise the `CREATE` statement is never executed, and SQL*Plus is just sitting at a prompting waiting for you to type in more code. (The line number prompt isn't shown in the log because of the `-s` flag).

Your script should end with:

```
...
PROCEDURE XLRI_BOM_ANALYSIS (
      ERRBUF           OUT   VARCHAR2,
      RETCODE          OUT   NUMBER,
      p_org_id         IN NUMBER
   );

END XLRIPHD_BOMREPORT_PKG;
/

EXIT;
```

Your `.pkg` script may well have the same issues.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation was perfect. I tried using / and EXIT in the Unix prompt with the same result. Much appreciated Alex.